# ¿Por qué la condición validarID_Usuario no me me regresa True? Python

Tags: python, condiciones, clase, booleano, metodos

Aprendo programación.
Estoy creando una clase para hacer CRUD Class CRUD_Users():. Voy implementando cada método el comportamiento del CRUD. El programa Crea, y Visualiza al usuario en estos momentos. El problema es el metodo validarID_Usuario. Cuando creo 2 usuarios con la misma cedula el programa debería negarme. Pero lo crea

```
ID = 0
#Inicializamos la variable en 0 para luego ser incrementada por cada usuario registrado

#Lista de usuarios para almacenar todos los datos correspondiente
lista_usuarios = []
#Usamos diccionario para establecer datos especificos y orden del usuario
usr_prototype = {
    'ID'     : '',
    'Nombre' : '',
    'Cedula' : ''
}
```

```
class CRUD_Users():
    def obtener_datos_usuario(self):
        clear()
        global ID
        print("[Agregar cliente al sistema]\n\n")

        for i in range(1):
            usr_prototype['Nombre'] = input("Nombre: ")
            usr_prototype['Cedula'] = int(input("Cédula: "))
            validador_Users = self.validarID_Usuario(usr_prototype["Cedula"])

            if validador_Users:
                #Si el retorno es False
                print("\n[ERROR]: La cedula que desea registrar ya existe en el sistema.\nSi el programa presenta problemas técnicos comuniquese con el Soporte.\n\n")
                inPausa = EnterPause()
                break
            else:
                #Si el retorno es True
                print("¡Usuario registrado exitosamente!\n\n [DATOS]")
                ID += 1
                usr_prototype["ID"] = ID
                lista_usuarios.append(usr_prototype)
                self.mostrar_datos_usuario(usr_prototype["Cedula"])
                #Pasamos por parametro la cedula de la lista ingresada para mostrar los datos
```

```
    def validarID_Usuario(self, validarCedula):
        #Metodo para validar Cedula del Usuario
        for i in lista_usuarios:
        #Recorremos cada elemento de la lista
            if i["Cedula"] == validarCedula:
            #El elemento que se recorre es el valor de la clave Cedula
                return False
            else:
                return True

    def mostrar_datos_usuario(self, ced):
        for i in lista_usuarios:
            if i["Cedula"] == ced:
                for key, value in i.items():
                    print(f"{key}: {value}")
                break
        inPausa = EnterPause()
```

Crei que poner la lista de usuarios en global ayudaria pero no resultó

Comment: Has comprovado que valor tiene validarCedula?

Comment: El verdadero problema me acabo de fijar, es que lista_usuarios esta fuera de clase y no sé como instanciarla dentro de la clase especificamente en los metodos. Por ende, no acumula los valores, solo ingresa uno y es reemplazado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soluciones:

1. Almacenar valores en la lista

Agregue un constructor a CRUD_Users pasando por parametro lista_usuarios

```
class CRUD_Users():
def __init__(self, listaUsers):
    self.listaUsers = listaUsers
```

por ende tengo otra función de elegirMenu() que no agregue, y por los excepciones me pedia agregar un valor por referencia

```
if menu_type == 1:
    registrarUsuario = CRUD_Users(lista_usuarios)
    registrarUsuario.obtener_datos_usuario()
```

2. Seguia con problemas y el problema también era usr_prototype. Estaba reutilizando el mismo diccionario para cada iteración del bucle. Lo moví dentro del for. Así al crear un nuevo diccionario en cada iteración, cada usuario tenga su propio conjunto

   for i in range(1):
   usr_prototype = {
   'ID'     : '',
   'Nombre' : '',
   'Cedula' : ''
   }
3. Luego que se almacenará, las validaciones eran contrarias. Luego de crear un 2do usuario me decía que ya existe. Solo invertí el valor booleano en el Retorno en validarID_Usuario y listo.